# Problem with going to the next item in a list

Tags: c#

The following pertains to C#
there are 4 lists:

1. `INRHolidays` list: Contains all the holidays and weekends
2. `CashFlowDates`: Containing all the dates for 10 years from today
3. `CashFlowDatesFinal`: Containing all the dates in CashFlowdates except the INRHolidays
4. `TenorDates`: Containing some specific dates i.e 6m, 9m, 12m, 1y, 2y, 3y, 4y, 5y, 7y, and 10y from now.

Now I want to check whether these specific dates in the `TenorDates` are Holidays or not. If not then they should be directly added to new list, `HolidayAdjustedTenorDates`, otherwise the next working day from `CashFlowDates` should be added.

20 is just a number as I didn't understand how to put the boundary condition.

```
var HolidayAdjustedTenorDates = new List<string>();

foreach (var a in TenorDates)
{
    if (CashFlowDatesFinal.Contains(a))
    { 
        HolidayAdjustedTenorDates.Add(a); 
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {
             if(CashFlowDatesFinal.Contains(
                  Convert.ToDateTime(a).AddDays(i).ToShortDateString()))
             { 
                 HolidayAdjustedTenorDates.Add(
                  Convert.ToDateTime(a).AddDays(i).ToShortDateString());
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an exception or what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact problem, that you are not getting the right date or that you don't know how to write the loop, to put the boundary condition?

You may try a while loop:

```
int i = 1;
while(!CashFlowDatesFinal.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(a).AddDays(i).ToShortDateString()))
{
    i++;
}
HolidayAdjustedTenorDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(a).AddDays(i).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Problem is that the foreach loop is not getting executed for all the items of TenorDates. When the first IF statement id not executed, the program stays in the Else loop and returns the values starting from the first element of TenorDates.

Comment: You mean that in the else loop maybe a date later than the next element in TenorDates is added? Could you post an example showing what is wrong or describe it more thoroughly?

Comment: Example. 4 years from now, the date will be 8th Oct 2022 which is going to be a saturday. This date is included in the INRHolidays. Therefore, the list HolidaysAdjustedTenorDates should contain the next working date, 10th October 2022. This is happening.

Comment: You say 'This is happening'. Then what is the issue? That it is not selecting October 10th 2022?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot place a comment so sorry to post an answer but :

1-you should really improve your code. C# is a strong typed language, so avoid to use `var`, but use the real type instead

2-don't work directly on `a`, use temporarily variables.

This done, you could avoid mistakes and you can facilitate debugging.

For example, in your code, if `CashFlowDatesFinal` contains `DateTime`, you don't have to compare with `string` (made by `ToShortDateString()`)

Comment: Using `var` is absolutely ok, you are still working with a strongly typed variable. `var` is just a convenience to avoid typing the actual type, the compiler will infer it

Comment: There is absolulely no reason to use `var` here (not anonymous type or linq query for example). You should use `var` only when it's is strictly necessary. It makes code less readable and more complex.

Comment: I may agree that `var` can get to less readable code, here `var a` is a string, and you actually need to check the following code to understand it. My point is that using `var` you don't miss any compiler help related to strongly typed language, i.e. compilation will fail if you use `a` as something else as a string. `var someMeaningfulName = new ClassWithAComplexAndLongName();` is perfectly ok to me